Strange solution to a second order linear differential equation
In the following equation:
$$y''+2y'+2y=10e^{x}+6e^{-x} \cos(x).$$
The homogenous solution is:
$$y_h = c_1e^{-x}\cos(x)+c_2e^{-x} \sin(x)$$
which should mean the particular solution is:
$$y_p = Axe^{-x}\cos(x) + Bxe^{-x}\sin(x) + Ce^x$$
However, this doesn't work, and produces a false statement. It should be:
$$Axe^{-x}\sin(x) + Be^x$$
Why is that so? Why do we emit the equation itself in the particular solution?

Doesn't this just mean $A=0$ in your $y_p$ expression?
